# Can't install python, pip related apps through Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am using below ansible yml file to install python, pip, etc.

`roles/python/main.yml`:

```
---

- name: python
  apt:
    pkg: python

- name: python-pip
  apt:
    pkg: python-pip

- name: mongopy
  pip:
    pkg: mongopy

- name: mtools
  pip:
    pkg: mtools
```

when I run `ansible-playbook` on this script, I get below

```
PLAY [ec2] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xxxxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
xxxxxap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

there is no error on them but I checked these apps are not installed on the remote host. What wrong with my yml file? Is there any place I can check what the error is?

below is my playbook:

`python.yml`:

```
---

- hosts: ec2
  remote_user: ubuntu
  roles:
    - python
```

below is the command I run:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts python.yml`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added playbook and the command I used to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no tasks in your `python` role. Please have a look at the [role structure](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_roles.html#roles).

> If `roles/x/tasks/main.yml` exists, tasks listed therein will be added to the play

Tasks file (`main.yml`) should be placed in the `tasks` subdirectory of the role, not in the main role's directory.

---

And this has nothing to do with how you described the problem (installing Python or Pip). Even if you replaced the tasks with a single `debug` task which displays `Hello world` by default, it would not run.